# apt-get install nautilus-dropbox uses high cpu resources

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, deb, dropbox

It is likely that the native dropbox app for Linux that is installed by

`apt-get install nautilus-dropbox`
this method has a bug which is why it uses high CPU resources ?
How to fix this?

Comment: What's your question? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Problem solved ???